# Java Counting unique values in a queue

Tags: java, count, queue, unique

```
int uniqueCount = 0;
System.out.println("List Cities Visited:");

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    System.out.println((i+1)+". "+(String)cityTrack.dequeue());

}

System.out.println("Unique Cities: "+uniqueCount);
```

Basically, I added a list of cities into a queue. And I am to print it out as shown above, and to count the number of unique cities there are. Any ideas? I'm quite new to this.

EDIT: Solved. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you add the cities to a Set. Then the answer is simply the size of the Set. Otherwise, you can still use a Set in your for-loop to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8 comes the stream API:s which supports the `distinct`-method. The following code can be used:

```
Collection<String> cities = new ArrayDeque<>();
cities.add("Detroit");
cities.add("NYC");
cities.add("Boston");
cities.add("Boston");

// Count the number of unique cities
final long uniqueCities = cities.stream().distinct().count();

// Prints all of the cities (including duplicates) and removes them from the 
// queue (i.e. performs a dequeue) which is the same way as you showed in the example
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, cities.size())
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + ". " + cities.remove()));

// Prints the unique cities counter
System.out.println("Unique: " + uniqueCities); // -> Unique: 3
```

The `distinct`-method requires that the `hashCode`-method is properly implemented (which it already is for the `String` class).

Resources:

- [Learn more about streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)
- [Learn more about hashCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29)

Tip, if you need to create your own hash the `Objects.hash` method works fine. You simple pass the args that should be part of the `hashCode`.

```
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(attr1, attr2, attr3);
}
```

Also, note that by using the `remove`-method (which is the same as `dequeue` in your example) the elements are removed from the queue. If this is not the intention a simple loop with a counter will do just fine like in the example below:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
cities.stream()
        .map(city -> counter.incrementAndGet() + ". " + city)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

> ....and to count the number of unique cities there are.....

You can use `Set` here because it only contains unique elements.

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    queue.add(1);
    queue.add(1);
    queue.add(1);
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.addAll(queue);
    System.out.println(set.size());
```

***OUTPUT***

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you mention in your code. Create a temp queue named e.g. `uniqueCityTrack` and check for each you have checked and entered.

```
int uniqueCount = 0;
System.out.println("List Cities Visited:");
CityTrack uniqueCityTrack = new CityTrack();
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    System.out.println((i+1)+". "+(String)cityTrack.dequeue());
    while(uniqueCityTrack.hasNext){
        if(!uniqueCityTrack.contain((String)cityTrack.dequeue()){
            uniqueCount++;
        }
    }
uniqueCityTrack.enqueue((String)cityTrack.dequeue());
}

System.out.println("Unique Cities: "+uniqueCount);
```

Comment: while(uniqueCityTrack.hasNext)

unfortunately, after I changed the above code to my code's needs, i realized that .hasNext doesn't work. I'm using netbeans IDE is there another way to write uniqueCityTrack.hasNext?

Comment: Which Queue you are using?

Comment: A queue class offered by my course teacher. She said that there isn't any hasNext method in it. But it's ok, I solved the problem by using collections frequency. I personally didnt like it at first.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to an HashSet and get the size.